# datatable fixed header not working inside dt-options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am using datatable to show the table and I want that the should not scroll when the data is scrolled, it should be fixed. I searched it out and found to use  .withFixedHeader({bottom: true,top:true}) in data table options but it is not working.

```js
scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withBootstrap()
    .withDisplayLength(parsedSettings.NoOfRecords ? parsedSettings.NoOfRecords : 20)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    
    .withFixedHeader({bottom: true,top:true})
    /*
    and many other options 
    */
```

```css
 table.table thead th{
        position: relative;
    }

    .table-condensed thead tr th{
        padding-top: 10px !important;
    }

    table.table thead .sorting_asc:before{
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -11px;
        left: 46%;
    }

    table.table thead .sorting_desc:before{
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -11px;
        left: 46%;
    }
    .dataTables_scrollBody table thead tr th{
        padding-top: 0px!important;
        padding-bottom: 0px!important;
    }

    .custom-scroller{
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .no-borders td,.no-borders th{
        border: none!important;
    }
```

```html
  <table  datatable dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-options="dtOptions" style="width:100%;"></table>
```

I added the dependency 'datatables.fixedheader', but even it is not working And the header is also scrolling.
I also found that by using jquery we can do it

```
($('#myTable').DataTable( {
    fixedHeader: true
} );
)
```

but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: I suggest you include the dataTables FixedHeader plug-in as well.

Comment: Give your data table id - myTable and put this function in the script at the bottom of your page in document.ready function. Try that might work.

Comment: I want to include it in my dtOptions.